# ServletWebServer or WebServer?

Tags: java, xml-rpc, primitive

What is the advantage of using 
org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.ServletWebServer 
instead of 
or.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.WebServer
when working with XMLRPC in JAVA?

Can I use functions that return array of primitives types or nulls with ServletWebServer?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation sais](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/server.html), that if you use the ServletWebServer you will have the possibility to migrate to another servlet based webserver like Tomcat. I didn't experience any other advantages over the WebServer superclass.

> If you still insist in using the
>   WebServer, it is recommended to use
>   its subclass, the ServletWebServer
>   instead, which offers a minimal subset
>   of the servlet API. In other words,
>   you keep yourself the option to
>   migrate to a real servlet engine
>   later.

Answer (score 0):

I recall using WebServer to launch a standalone RPC Server in a Swing application. My guess is that when using ServletWebServer you'll need the *servlet-api* jars.(see @Daff answer)

- If you're using the library in a non Web application, go for WebServer class, it will probably suit your needs.
- If you're using Apache XMLRPC in a Web application, why not use their servlet and register your handlers?

Read the Apache XMLRPC documentation to see which type you're able to return and how to add  extensions(if needed).